# swift 3.0 check UIImageView is nil or not

Tags: swift3, uiimageview, uiimage

I am using a placeholder image "a.png" in my `UIImageView` in viewcontroller1. When the user will choose any image from his phone gallery then the selected image will be shown in the UIImageview. Now if the user goes from viewcontroller1 to viewcontroller2, the I have to check my image view is empty or not. For this I am writing :

```
if myimageview.image == nil
    { // show alert

... }
```

But, the code is not working, as the `imageview` already contains a placeholder image.

Can any one please suggest me how can I validate my `imageview`?

Comment: did you get your solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can check by your `placeholder` image.

```
let img = UIImage(named: "a.png")
//Now check if the img has changed or not:
if imageView1?.image != img {
//Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have assigned placeholder image to imageView.image property, so its better to keep any boolean check to know whether user has updated image or not. Keep this boolean value to false, as user pick image from gallery or camera make this true. 
On navigating to viewcontroller2 check boolean variable's value.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a boolean property in your model

```
var hasCustomImage = false
```

After choosing a custom image set the property to `true` and check this

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3.0 code**

first solution is ..

```
 imgview.image= nil
```

secound soultion is..

```
  imgview.image= UIImage.init(named: "")
```

Comment: OP has already tried the first solution in the question. And you don't need to `init` in the second solution